# Adding percentage to a price field incl. currency code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add 10% to a price field via javascript and so far i haven't been able to, and was hoping you guys would be able to help.

The field incl. currency code etc.

I did try something in this direction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var Total = $("#cashamount");
      Total.val(Total.val() * 1.1);
    });
</script>
```

But that didn't work ;(

The price field shows up like the following.

```
<span id="cashamount" class="additional xxlarge carrental_total_amount">48,300.00 ISK</span>
```

After adding the 10% to the price, it should say in this example:

```
<span id="cashamount" class="additional xxlarge carrental_total_amount">53,130.00 ISK</span>
```

Any ideas are welcome, and i would really appreciate help on this matter as i do think it's fairly simple but i'm not very well into Javascripting.

Comment: I think your problem is, that you cant do  "* 1.1" because you have characters in your value.

Comment: I did try a hardcoded field with just a value of "500" and that also didn't work.

Comment: You're calling `.val()` on a span, this does not work use either `.html()`  or `.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this: (solution below)

> The **.val()** method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of elements, the
>   .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no
>   option is selected, it returns null, **[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**
>
> The **.text()** method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method,
>   **[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

So, one solution would be next:

```
var Total = $("#cashamount");
var totalNumber = Number(Total.text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
Total.text((totalNumber * 1.1).toFixed(2));
//Add currency to this
```

Here's [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/503b6q4r/1/)

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for the help. It works and i was able to modify it to format currency etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = $("#cashamount").html(); // Fetching the value
var xSplit = x.split(" "); // Splitting the currency and ammount and storing it in array.

var intAmmt = +xSplit[0].replace(/,/g , ""); // Removing comma and Making it a integer
var newAmmt = intAmmt*1.1; // Incrementing by 10%    
var y = newAmmt.toLocaleString() + " " + xSplit[1]; // Adding the currency sign with a space
$("#cashamount").html(y); // Setting the html;
```

So you can create a function for this:

```
function updateVal(elem){
    var x = elem.html(); // Fethching the value
    var xSplit = x.split(" "); // Splitting the currency and ammount and storing it in array.

    var intAmmt = +xSplit[0].replace(/,/g , ""); // Removing comma and Making it a integer
    var newAmmt = intAmmt*1.1; // Incrementing by 10%    
    var y = newAmmt.toLocaleString() + " " + xSplit[1]; // Adding the currency sign with a space
    elem.html(y); // Setting the html;
}
```

and use it as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   updateVal($("#cashamount"))
});
```

Comment: No, `span` doesnt have a `val` attribute.. You should use `.html()` or `.text()`. If it helps kindly consider an upvote and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's explainable, i tried this here https://jsfiddle.net/oe1nak4e/ but i'm not getting it working, can this be due to the jquery version ?.

Comment: Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oe1nak4e/4/, You need to use it on `DOM Ready` so wrap it in `$(function(){ ... });` and i replace `.val` to `.html`, i mistakenly typed it in answer.